# Line break in a variable in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I need to add a line break on the last variable.
I'm trying to put that variable in a text box, an I need the line seperate like it is here in the code.

Any help wold be much appreciated.

```
T89654 Send FPL with ATSM
 fdd clicktab             message_editor
 fdd clickbutton          message_editor.atsm
 fdd clickbutton          message_editor.atsm.clear
 fdd setfield             message_editor.atsm.message                  (FPL-BAW123-IS
                                                                       -C130/M-SIRWXY/C
                                                                       -RKPC1010
                                                                       -N0260F270 RATSU
                                                                       -RKSI0100
                                                                       -DOF/100414)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\n` to insert a line break:

```
fdd setfield      message_editor.atsm.message     (FPL-BAW123...\n...100414)
```

The robot framework users guide mentions this in the section [Forming escape sequences](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#escape-sequences).

Answer (score 1):

You can add `...`

```
 fdd setfield             message_editor.atsm.message                  (FPL
...    BAW123
...    IS
...    C130/M-SIRWXY/C
...    RKPC1010
...    N0260F270 RATSU
...    RKSI0100
...    DOF/100414)
```